# Haproxy Https and Vhost

Tags: proxy, haproxy

I am new to the Haproxy world and after many hours I have managed to work with certificate and in https mode. But now I have a new problem that seems to be due to Vhost on the target servers.

I read that you need to create a rule to point to the vhost, when it goes through the domain instead of loading the web, the default page of the server appears, as it loads the IP instead of the domain.

Can you give me an example?

```
    frontend www-https
    bind www.dominio.dev:443 ssl crt /etc/letsencrypt/live/sddd.net/1.pem
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats auth  cda:cda
    balance roundrobin

    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port 443
    http-response add-header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000

    acl letsencrypt-acl path_beg /.well-known/acme-challenge/
  # use_backend letsencrypt-backend if letsencrypt-acl
    http-request redirect scheme https unless { ssl_fc }
    default_backend www-backend


backend www-backend
   redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
   #http-request redirect scheme https if http
   server www-1 www1.dominio.dev:443 ssl verify none
   server www-2 www2.dominio.dev:443 ssl verify none maxconn 5000
   server www-3 www3.dominio.dev:443 ssl verify none
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all "bind" directive in haproxy configuration shoud be your haproxy server ip adderss.
first create frontend httpd, frontend https, and backand.

If you have redirects from http to https on backand www1.dominio.dev, www2.dominio.dev, www3.dominio.dev servers please disable it make listen to port 80.  Haproxy will redirect http to https

Here is en example:

```
frontend http
    bind haproxy_ip_address:80
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto http
    use_backend www-backend if { hdr(host) -i dominio.dev }

frontend https
    bind haproxy_ip_address:443 ssl crt /etc/letsencrypt/live/sddd.net/1.pem
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
    http-response replace-header  ^Server.* Server Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    http-response replace-header ^Set-Cookie:\ (.*) Set-Cookie \1;\ Secure if secure
    http-request add-header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;\ includeSubDomains;\ preload
    option http-server-close
    option http-keep-alive

    use_backend www-backend if { hdr(host) -i dominio.dev }
    use_backend www-backend if { req_ssl_sni -i dominio.dev }

backend www-backend
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option accept-invalid-http-response
    retries 3
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    option forwardfor
    server www-1 www1.dominio.dev:80 ssl verify none
    server www-2 www2.dominio.dev:80 ssl verify none maxconn 5000
    server www-3 www3.dominio.dev:80 ssl verify none
```

Also please check if configuration is valid with: "haproxy -c -V -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg"